# Deeplab for road segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, deeplab

I want to use deeplab v3 pre-trained model which is trained on cityscape data set for inference my custom images. I downloaded mobilenetv2_coco_cityscapes_trainfine checkpoint file from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md this url.

So how to do inference for my custom road image?

Answer (score 0):

This is a FAQ in Deeplab's Github repo, check question 2 in this link for more info:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/faq.md